# Mass Rename of Variables and Getter/Setter Methods in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a large library of Hibernate-annotated bean classes with inconsistent variable naming. For example, in one class, a variable might be named "acceptanceDate" but in another it might be named "dateAccepted". Each class has a get/set method as well.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to rename these variables across the board AS WELL AS rename their accessor methods. (And even better: open projects in eclipse would update their own references to use the new names).

This is probably a long shot, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Are these beans accessed from JSP or JSF files? Scripts?

Comment: Since they represent the data model of the application, they are accessed from multiple points, including JSP files.

Answer (score -1):

Such a functionality simply does not exist in Eclipse.  If I were you, I would write a utility class that would scan the given directory recursively for .java files and then parse them one by one to rename the getter / setter methods and their fields as per the convention needed.  Parsing does not have to be full-fledged as you are interested in only renaming the fields and their getter setters that match a specific criteria.

Other option is to manually refactor each instance variable and its getter setter using the **Refactor --> Rename** dialog of Eclipse.

Comment: State the reason before down vote as it would be helpful to know.